# Can't verify AWS cognito id token

Tags: php, amazon-cognito, auth0

I send a http request to my backend and I want to verify the id token in the cookie attached to this request.

I'm trying to verify with the follow  (copied the idea from here - https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0-php/jwt-validation )-

```
$this->config = [
    'supported_algs' => [ 'RS256' ],
    'valid_audiences' => [ /* Client Id from AWS Cognito  */ ],
    'authorized_iss' => [ "https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{userPoolId}/.well-known/jwks.json" ]
];
$verifier = new JWTVerifier($this->config);
$decoded_token = $verifier->verifyAndDecode($_COOKIE['id_token']);
```

And I'm getting an exception - Caught: `CoreException - We cannot trust on a token issued by https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{userPoolId} Api key is not valid`

What I'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: It's right there in the error message `Api key is not valid`

Comment: So what should I change to verify the id token properly ?

Comment: Try changing the `authorised_iss` to `https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{userPoolId}/`

Comment: I tried - same error

Comment: Try it again without the trailing slash `/`

Comment: You *are* replacing `{region}` and `{userPoolId}` with their proper values, right?

Comment: Strip `.well-known/jwks.json` off of the `authorized_iss` Only use `https://cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eu-central-1_o1pwvp1a4` or `https://cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eu-central-1_o1pwvp1a4/`